# how to access a struct within a list within a struct with a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm given a number i, and a pointer which points to a struct which contains a list of structs, basically what I want to do is go over all of the lists and look which struct in it has the number i.

```
typedef struct struct1 { int num; } struct1;

typedef struct struct2 {
  struct1 somestruct1;
  struct2 *pnext;
} struct2;

struct struct3 {
  struct2 somestruct2;
};
```

I'm new to coding and I can't seem to figure this out, here's how I'm trying to access a num field in some `struct1` given a pointer to `struct3`

```
struct3 temp->somestruct2.somestruct1.num ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct3 s3;

int num = s3.somestruct2.somestruct1.num;
```

or

```
struct3 *s3;

int num = s3->somestruct2.somestruct1.num;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your confusion might be due to whether to use a "." or a "->"

Here is a general rule...

If the item to the left is a pointer, use "->".  If it is not a pointer, use ".".

If "temp" is defined "struct struct3 temp", then temp is not a pointer.  Hence, it should be followed by a "." to access the sub-element(s) of temp.

The temp sub-element "somestruct1" is also not defined as a pointer in struct2; hence, to access the sub-element(s) of somestruct1, it should be followed by a ".".

```
temp.somestruct2.somestruct1.num
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how that can be done.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct struct1 { int num; } struct1;

typedef struct struct2 {
  struct1 somestruct1;
  struct struct2 *pnext;
} struct2;

struct struct3 {
  struct2 somestruct2;
};

int main()
{
    struct struct3* s = malloc(sizeof(struct struct3));

    s->somestruct2.somestruct1.num = 1;
    printf("%d\n", s->somestruct2.somestruct1.num);

    free(s);
}
```

Whenever you have a pointer, you must dereference it before you can use the thing it points to. The dereference operator is unary `*` and then `.` to access the structs members.

So long hand you could write

```
(*s).somestruct2.somestruct1.num = 1;
```

This is a very common operation and its also quite ugly, so an operator that combines them is `->`, hence

```
s->somestruct2.somestruct1.num = 1;
```